# Use param for remapping in launch file

Tags: bash, parameters, script, remapping, remap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have several nodes with common parameters so I tought it would be nice for debugging to have all of them just in one file and not in all of them. This is working fine but the problem is that remapping it is not able to retrieve this parameters. Is there any way for doing this? Either using the ROS API either scripting? This is an example of what I am trying to do:

```
<launch>
<node pkg="move_base" type="move_base" respawn="false" name="move_base" output="screen">
    <rosparam file="$(find car_navigation)/param/teb_local_planner_params.yaml" command="load" />

    <!-- Here are the params shared by several nodes -->
    <rosparam file="$(find car_bringup)/param/common_params.yaml" command="load" />

    <!-- Here is getting the parameter from the previous file and working properly-->
    <param name="x_size"            value="$(arg x_size)" />
    
    <!-- Here I am having the problem when remapping -->
    <remap from="cmd_vel"           to="$(arg vel_cmd_topic)"/>
    <remap from="max_speed"         to="$(arg max_speed)"/>
</node>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/255822/use-param-for-remapping-in-launch-file/) by [solosito](https://answers.ros.org/users/25128/solosito/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2017-02-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like you're missing some `<arg>` tags above your `<node>` tag. Try this:

```
<launch>
<!-- name is the name of the variable, default is the default value if no value is specified -->
<arg name="vel_cmd_topic" default="default_topic"/>
<arg name="max_speed" default="a.bc"/>
<node pkg="move_base" type="move_base" respawn="false" name="move_base" output="screen">
    <rosparam file="$(find car_navigation)/param/teb_local_planner_params.yaml" command="load" />

    <!-- Here are the params shared by several nodes -->
    <rosparam file="$(find car_bringup)/param/common_params.yaml" command="load" />

    <!-- Here is getting the parameter from the previous file and working properly-->
    <param name="x_size"            value="$(arg x_size)" />

    <!-- Here I am having the problem when remapping -->
    <remap from="cmd_vel"           to="$(arg vel_cmd_topic)"/>
    <remap from="max_speed"         to="$(arg max_speed)"/>
</node>
</launch>
```

From the terminal, type:

`roslaunch package_name launch_file_name.launch vel_cmd_topic:=topic_name max_speed:=x.yz`

and replace these placeholders with your own values. I've never done this with `<remap>` tags, but I don't see why it wouldn't work.

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2017-03-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [solosito](https://answers.ros.org/users/25128/solosito/) on 2017-03-27**:
I am not missing any argument, actually that's the point of my question. I am asking if there is any way to get the **vel_cmd_topic** and **max_speed** parameters from `common_params.yaml` for the remapping as I am doing with the **x_size** parameter.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-03-27**:
Why don't you post your `common_params.yaml`?

**Comment by [solosito](https://answers.ros.org/users/25128/solosito/) on 2017-03-28**:
Here you are:

#Common parameters
size_x: &size_x 0.8
vel_cmd: &vel_cmd 7
speed_max: &speed_max 0.9

#Params for motor1 and motor2
x_size: *size_x
vel_cmd_topic: *vel_cmd
max_speed: *speed_max

**Comment by [solosito](https://answers.ros.org/users/25128/solosito/) on 2017-03-28**:
It is working for ***size_x*** but not for ***vel_cmd_topic*** neither for ***max_speed***

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-03-28**:
Do you *have* to load these through a file? I know for sure that my method works for remapping topic names. I have a feeling that the way you're trying to do it won't work because you're loading the names as parameters and not as arguments, which is what you really want.

**Comment by [solosito](https://answers.ros.org/users/25128/solosito/) on 2017-03-28**:
It would be a really big improvement for testing because that parameters are being used in a lot of independent nodes, so when I want to test with another value for it, I have to go through all the files and change them there.

**Comment by [mustafaismail](https://answers.ros.org/users/39451/mustafaismail/) on 2019-01-13**:
hello have you managed to find a solution to this? cause i want to do exactly the same.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2019-01-13**:
@mustafaismail not sure as this question is nearly two years old. You should ask a new question and reference this one.